# Hide version in header with passenger standalone

Tags: nginx, passenger

I am starting my server as standalone (from command line) and realize the option --passenger_show_version_in_header does not exist in the passenger start command line.

Does anyone knows a way to hide the version in the header when starting standalone server from command-line ?

Comment: A header which is returned by passenger through to nginx as a proxy? nginx can filter/change such headers in its .conf file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access passenger_show_version_in_header through the [Advanced Configuration](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html#advanced_configuration).

Comment: # cp `passenger-config about resourcesdir`/templates/standalone/config.erb /etc/secretive.config.erb
# then in `http` add two rows like this:

http {
    server_tokens off;
    passenger_show_version_in_header off;
}

# Then:
# passenger start --nginx-config-template /etc/secretive.config.erb